# Python:How to implement getting the latest location

Tags: python

GOAL:-
I need to parse a file with the below input and get  the latest (builddate timestamp should be latest)location when the status is approved and builddate is the latest..I provided sample input and output,I have the code in perl,new to python,please suggest how can this be implemented in python

```
INPUT:-
Build:          M1234BAAAANAAW9321.1
Location:       \\dreyers\builds468\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAA9321.1
Comments:       Build completed, labeled, and marked for retention.
Status:         Approved
BuildDate:      10/25/2012 12:51:25


Build:          M1234BAAAANAAW9321.2
Location:       \\crmbld01\Builds\FAILED\M1234BAAAANAA9321.2
Comments:       The build is currently in a failed status.
Status:         Failed
BuildDate:      10/25/2012 19:37:17


Build:          M1234BAAAANAAW9321.3
Location:       \\freeze\builds427\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAA9321.3
Comments:       Build completed, labeled, and marked for retention.
Status:         Approved
BuildDate:      10/25/2012 19:43:28

OUTPUT:-\\freeze\builds427\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAA9321.3
```

Following is the perl code that achieves,I am new to python,please suggest how can I pythonize this code

```
$ echo 'Build:          M1234BAAAANAAW9321.1
Location:       \\dreyers\builds468\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAAW9321.1
Comments:       Build completed, labeled, and marked for retention.
Status:         Approved
BuildDate:      10/25/2012 12:51:25


Build:          M1234BAAAANAAW9321.2
Location:       \\crmbld01\Builds\FAILED\M1234BAAAANAAW9321.2
Comments:       The build is currently in a failed status.
Status:         Failed
BuildDate:      10/25/2012 19:37:17


Build:          M1234BAAAANAAW9321.3
Location:       \\freeze\builds427\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAAW9321.3
Comments:       Build completed, labeled, and marked for retention.
Status:         Approved
BuildDate:      10/25/2012 19:43:28
' | perl -e'

local $/ = "";
my ( $build_date, $location );
while ( <> ) {
next unless /status:\s+approved/i;
my $date = sprintf "%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", ( /builddate:\s+(\d
++)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/i )[ 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5 ];
if ( !defined $build_date || $build_date lt $date ) {
    ( $build_date, $location ) = ( $date, /location:\s+(.+)/i );
    }                                                           
}
```

print "$location\n";
'
\freeze\builds427\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAAW9321.3

I tried to write the following in python,doesnt seem to work,am wondering if there is a better implementation to achieve the goal..please suggest

```
for line_info in lines:

    line_info.find('Location')

    if line_info.find('Location') == 0:
        # Build Location
        print "  Found Build location"
        logString += "  Found Build location\n"
        location = line_info.split(" ")
        location1 = location[len(location)-1]
    elif line_info.find('Status') == 0:
        # Status
        print "  Found Status"
        logString += "  Found Status\n"
        status = line_info.split(" ")
        removeEmpty(status)
        status1 = status[1].strip()
        if status1 != "Approved"
        goto .start
    elif line_info.find('BuildDate') == 0:
        # Main Make
        print "  Found BuildDate"
        logString += "  Found BuildDate\n"
        builddate1 = line_info.split(" ")
        removeEmpty(builddate1)
        builddate1 = builddate1[1]
        #if builddate1 >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
lastLocation = None
lastTime = None
skip = False

bestLocation = None
bestTime = None

for line in text.split('\n'):    
    line.find('Location')
    if line.find('Location') == 0:
        # Build Location
        skip = False
        print "  Found Build location"
        lastLocation = line.split(":")[1].lstrip()       
    elif line.find('Status') == 0:
        # Status
        print "  Found Status"
        status = line.split(":")
        status1 = status[1].strip()
        if status1 != "Approved":
            skip = True
    elif line.find('BuildDate') == 0 and not skip:
        # Main Make
        print "  Found BuildDate"
        timeStr = line.split(":", 1)[1].lstrip()
        lastTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeStr, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        if bestTime == None or bestTime < lastTime:
            bestTime = lastTime
            bestLocation = lastLocation
print lastLocation
```

Comment: Geting the following error ,I doubt the formatting..   lastTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeStr, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  File "C:\python2.7.3\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:

Comment: @user1795998 If you found my answer helpful, please vote for my answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the problem into series of simpler steps:

1. read input line by line
2. collect 'name: value' pairs
3. group pairs into records (each record starts with 'Build' pair)
4. select 'Approved' records that have non-blank 'BuildDate', 'Location' values
5. find the latest record using given date/time format

Implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from datetime  import datetime
from itertools import groupby

# find all 'name: value' pairs
file = sys.stdin
pairs = ([s.strip() for s in line.partition(':')[::2]]
         for line in file if ':' in line)

# group records
def record_start(pair, count=[False]):
    """Mark start of a record."""
    if pair[0] == 'Build':
        count[0] = not count[0]
    return count[0]
records = (dict(record) for _, record in groupby(pairs, record_start))

approved = (r for r in records if r.get('Status') == 'Approved' and
            all(r.get(name) for name in "BuildDate Location".split()))

# find latest record
def get_date(record):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(record['BuildDate'], '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
    except ValueError:
        return datetime.min # handle invalid date strings

latest = max(approved, key=get_date)
assert get_date(latest) != datetime.min
print(latest['Location'])
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/tgUVfj)

```
\\freeze\builds427\INTEGRATION\M1234BAAAANAA9321.3
```